# How can I access a file and write to it from a nodejs executable made with nexe?

Tags: node.js, executable, nexe

I'm trying to modify a text file outside my nodejs executable that I made with nexe https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe .

However my executable is unable to detect the file. They're both in the same directory. What do I do?

Comment: You say that it is unable to detect the file, but what is your code, and what does it produce?

Comment: My code reads a file with a specific name.txt and puts each line into an array. Usually this file is detected when you put it in the same directory as the script however once you compile it's unable to detect its existence.